# Node js: not found ruby.exe

Tags: ruby, node.js, gruntjs, premailer

iam new to node js, ruby grunt etc. And i want to use premailer for my e-mail templates. So i installed node js, ruby, grunt and premailer but when i try to grunt it i get this error message:

```
    C:\Users\Noeel\Desktop\mail>grunt
    Running "premailer:main" (premailer) task
    Fatal error: Error: not found: ruby.exe
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNOXc.jpg
I followed several guides and searched the problem on google but no luck.

Comment: `grunt-premailer` -> ["Requirements" -> "Ruby >= 1.9.3"](https://github.com/dwightjack/grunt-premailer#requirements). Did you install Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be related to premailer required dependencie.

1. Download [Ruby](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/rubyinstaller-2.4.4-1/rubyinstaller-devkit-2.4.4-1-x64.exe)
2. Install
3. Restart your command line
4. Have fun!